# I want to display another model in the home admin site page django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In the admin site I display custom users, I mean in admin.py I wrote

```
from .models import User, Product, Address
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    fieldsets =  (
        *UserAdmin.fieldsets,
        (
            'Additional fields:',
            {
                'fields': (
                    'phone_number',
                    'billing_address',
                    'shipping_address',
                )
            }
        )
    )

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

User is my model that inherits from AbstractUser, I want to display another model too which is called Product. How to do that?
Here it is the second model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    SKU = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price =MoneyField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=4,default_currency='USD')

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='images', 
                                 on_delete=models.RESTRICT,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you struggling with? It's covered in [the basic tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin) and you already did a more complex setup with the User.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

admin.site.register(Product)
```

Comment: I know that but I need to make a custom user so when I did as you said the users didn't show in the admin site page only the products. Is there a way to handle custom users to be displayed with the products too?

Comment: As I read in the documentation if it is AbstractUser then to view the model in admin we use admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin) so I can't register after it the products?

Comment: Okay I have just started learning django so it is all new to me. I didn't know that I should create another another app with products so I can register it, so it seems that's what I was missing.

Comment: You don't need another app. Just add `admin.site.register(Product)` under the `admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)`. Please **accept** the answer if it was helpful

Comment: Each `admin.site.register` just adds another model to the admin panel, you can do it for every model you have without issues @MennaT-AllahMagdy